# How to make fadeIn and fadeOut effecet with delay of 3second using CSS for same div element or <h1>

Tags: css, frontend, css-animations, web-frontend

> I want to apply fadeIn and fadeOut effect on  element or any other
>   div tag with 3second dlay. answer CSS based only not use jQuery.
>   thanks

Comment: post your code that you've tried so far. otherwise your question is going to be closed and no-one will be able to give you an answer.

Comment: Welcome to SO, in order to get an answer, you will need to post the code you have tried as stated by @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal + ask for a specific isue. We can't do the whole thing for you. For more info please see here : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: HTML   `<h2 class="fadein fadeout ">My hedding goes here...</h2>`<br>

Comment: **CSS**<br>`.fadein{
    opacity:0;
    animation:fadein 4s infinite;    
}

@keyframes fadein{
    from{opacity:0;}
    to{opacity:1;}
}
.fadeout{
    opacity:1;
    animation:fadeout 3s infinite;
    animation-delay:5s;
}
@keyframes fadeout{
    from{opacity:1;}
    to{opacity:0;}
}`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/azhrhussain/pqry93n7/

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal + here is my code...kindly help

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you the benefit of the doubt, but you can find an answer with minimal effort searching either SO or online...but here goes...a quick example of a fade out...reverse for fade in:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85m2kbdx/2/)

HTML

```
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background:red;
}
div:hover {
    -webkit-animation:fadeOut 1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:3s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    -moz-animation:fadeOut 1s;
    -moz-animation-delay:3s;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation:fadeOut 1s;
    animation-delay:3s;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
    from {
        opacity:1;
    }
    to {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeOut {
    from {
        opacity:1;
    }
    to {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
    from {
        opacity:1;
    }
    to {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
```

Comment: not use any hover effect... first it adds fadein animation and delay of 5second and then fadeout animation,,,

Comment: **I want to make like** http://jsfiddle.net/azhrhussain/n4mKw/2526/embedded/result/

Comment: **but instead of jQuery I want this with CSS**